# Using OpenGL VBOs with custom classes/datatructures

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, vbo

I am trying to optimize the drawing of my quads (currently using `glBegin` and `glEnd`), and I read that a VBO is a better way to do this. My issue is that I don't have a basic array of `GLuint` with an index array, but rather custom classes to hold the values:

`Location.hpp`: Holds x, y, and z info

```
class Location {
public:
    Location(int x_, int y_, int z_);
    ~Location();

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};
```

`Face.hpp`: Holds 4 `Location*`s that mark the corners

```
class Face {
public:
    Face(Location* bl_, Location* br_, Location* tr_, Location* tl_); // Using point
    Face(int bl_[3], int br_[3], int tr_[3], int tl_[3]); // Using {x, y, z} int array
    ~Face();
    Location* bl = NULL; // Bottom Left
    Location* br = NULL; // Bottom Right
    Location* tr = NULL; // Top Right
    Location* tl = NULL; // Top Left
};
```

My question, is that I have a vector of faces (`std::vector<Face*> facesToRender;`) that I would like to display on the screen.

Right now I have a loop to do this:

Info:

The `Chunk` class creates a `facesToRender` and I believe this is where I can put a `vboId`)

`chunks` is an array of `Chunk*`s

```
glPushMatrix();
    for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
        Chunk* chunk = chunks[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < chunk->facesToRender.size(); j++) {
            Face* f = chunk->facesToRender[j];
            srand(i); // Create a color per chunk
            glColor3ub(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glVertex3i(f->bl->x, f->bl->y, f->bl->z);
            glVertex3i(f->br->x, f->br->y, f->br->z);
            glVertex3i(f->tr->x, f->tr->y, f->tr->z);
            glVertex3i(f->tl->x, f->tl->y, f->tl->z);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
glPopMatrix();
```

My question is how to process this `facesToRender` vector into a VBO to have it display. I am a beginner at OpenGL and C++ (although I know other languages, so sorry if I made some big mistake with the classes).

If any additional info is needed please comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to ensure that the vertex coordinates are in a contiguous and contiguous area in memory and are not fragmented into a lot of little pieces. Use `Location bl, br, tr, tl` instead of `Location *bl ...` and `std::vector<Face>` instead of `std::vector<Face*>`. Then you have a consecutive list of vertex coordinates which can be bound to a vertex buffer object:

```
class Face {
public:
    Location bl;
    Location br;
    Location tr;
    Location tl;
};

std::vector<Location> faces;
```

Create the vetrtex array object and bind the data

```
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers( 1, &vbo );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faces.size()*sizeof(*faces.data()), faces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

Draw the mesh:

```
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo );
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_INT, sizeof(Location), nullptr );
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );    

glPushMatrix();
for (int i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
    Chunk* chunk = chunks[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < chunk->facesToRender.size(); j++) {
        Face* f = chunk->facesToRender[j];
        srand(i); // Create a color per chunk

        glColor3ub(rand()%255, rand()%255, rand()%255);            
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, j*4, 4);
    }
}
glPopMatrix();

glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

---

As an alternative you can create a list of vertex coordinates and a list of faces which each contains the 4 indices of the corner coordinates.

```
std::vector<Location> vertices;

struct Face
{
    int bl;
    int br;
    int tr;
    int tl;
};

std::vector<Face> faces;
```

Indexed vertex cordiaten can be drawn by [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

Comment: Is it supposed to be `std::vector<Location> faces` or `std::vector<Face> faces`

Comment: @Minebomber In the 2nd case it has to be `std::vector<Face> faces`, of course. Thanks.